# How to find the decompression algorithms a browser supports

Tags: javascript, compression

Is it possible to determine which algorithms a browser supports in javascript (e.g. `br`, `gzip`)?  Specifically, which Content-Encodings the Fetch API will transparently decompress

Comment: Like from the [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) Request Header?

Comment: @Thomas yes - the default value the browser sets when making requests